# How to display HTML5 Video Tag in Circle shape?

Tags: css, video, html5-video, shapes, css-shapes

I have tried this in css "border-radius:100%;", but it is not giving 100% circle.

Following are css and html

**HTML**

```
<div class="web-cam">

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.web-cam video {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more HTML & CSS context.

Comment: Works fine for me. What is not working?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Style the containing div and the video element separately. Add a [`-webkit-mask-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-mask-image)
 to the containing div.

> The `-webkit-mask-image` CSS property sets the mask image for an element. A mask image clips the visible portion of an element according to the mask image's transparency.

The code below creates an arbitrary circular radial gradient to use as the mask, but you could also use `url()` to specify an online circular PNG image for the clipping mask (as presented in [Mozilla's doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-mask-image)).

HTML:

```
<div class="web-cam">
  <video controls>
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  </video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.web-cam { 
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 125px;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white 100%, black 100%);
}

video {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -125px;
  left: -125px;
}
```

Unfortunately, you'll lose your default controller, but there are many ways to build your own custom controller:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-custom-controls-for-html5-videos

http://dev.opera.com/articles/custom-html5-video-player-with-css3-and-jquery/#sec1

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/html5-multimedia-pt3.html

Comment: Why is your `border-radius` twice that of `height`/`width`? You should only need half (`125px`) instead of double.

Comment: @ajp15243, because I was quickly playing with different overall settings, and I forgot to downsize. I've edited my answer above; thanks for the tip.

Comment: I put in some actual sample videos, and the video container seems to be ignoring the `border-radius` with regards to `overflow: hidden`, at least for me in Chrome 36 on Linux: http://jsbin.com/canicaco/2/edit (you can play the video by right-clicking it, which gives you some basic controls)

Comment: @ajp15243, thanks for the extra info and showing that `overflow` wouldn't work on an actual video. I've found another CSS rule that may help (see edit above).

Comment: Works now for me! Pity that it's a WebKit property. I wonder if there are equivalent Mozilla/Opera/IE ones.

Comment: JSBIN redirects to a random demo

Comment: Outdated JSBin link now removed.